# How to use "contribution" and "contributions"

Tags: vocabulary, singular-vs-plural

How do I know whether I should use the singular or plural form of *contribution*?

I did an exercise.
The …………… of artists could not be exaggerated.

The answer is *contribution*.

Why didn't it use the plural form?

Comment: You ask why the answer is plural, yet the answer you gave is in singular.

Answer (score 1):

Either singular or plural is correct. (Based on context and meaning.)

It depends on if you are expressing it as a mass noun or a countable noun.

If you want to emphasize individual *contributions*, you would use the plural:

> Among all of the artists, eleven different contributions were made.

If you want to emphasize the idea of *contribution* in general (the totally if what was contributed or its nature), you would the singular (from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contribution)):

> The money was raised by voluntary contribution.